# Avoid or eliminate duplicated/reverse results in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7jNS.jpg)

I am looking for pairs in two columns in a csv. If it finds A-B and B-A include just A-B in the dictionary. I wrote the following script:

```
dataset = list(zip(col1,col2))
for a,b in dataset:
    if (a,b) and (b,a) in dataset:
        dic [a] = b
```

But obviously I only need one and the output is:

```
{'A': 'B', 'C': 'B', 'B': 'A', 'D': 'C', 'F': 'C', 'H': 'C', 'J': 'X', 'X': 'J'}
```

As you see it is duplicated sometimes (for example, D:C is correct but it only appears once, I don't know why)

How can I avoid those duplicates or eliminate from the dictionary the "reverse forms"?

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simple addition:

```
if (a,b) and (b,a) in dataset \
    and a < b :
```

This gets you only one of the two.  It also assumes (as in your example) that there is no row containing the same value twice.

Comment: it works! but it also eliminates C-D from the output being C-D (or D-C) correct... I edited the question to add also my file and show it complete if you can help me

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  There's no file included in your post -- just a link -- and you haven't included the problem code and output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check both pairs in each step. Instead you only need to check if `b` is in the dictionary and if so, whether `dic[b] != a`.

The reason for this is that we are always adding from `col1` as the key, so we only need to see if the reversed value has already been added.

```
col1 = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'X', 'F', 'H', 'J']
col2 = ['B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'J', 'C', 'C', 'X']

dic = {}
for a, b in zip(col1, col2):
    if (b not in dic) or (dic[b] != a):
        dic[a] = b

#{'A': 'B', 'C': 'B', 'D': 'C', 'F': 'C', 'H': 'C', 'X': 'J'}
```

However if you only wanted to keep one copy of each pair where both versions existed, you would need a slightly different approach.

First create a dictionary with all of the common pairs. Then iterate as before, and only add if both versions exist. Use the same logic as above to avoid duplicates.

```
d = dict(zip(col1, col2))
dic = {}
for a, b in d.items():
    if (a in d) and (b in d) and (d[a] == b) and (d[b] == a):
        if (b not in dic) or (dic[b] != a):
            dic[a] = b

#{'A': 'B', 'J': 'X'}
```